# TPL WPF MVVM How to make it work?

Tags: .net, wpf, mvvm, task-parallel-library, mvvm-light

We got a long running job that takes a job details list and shares no state trying to run in a WPF MVVM .Net 4 project. It appears the Task Parallel Library would be the best choice as it runs on background thread(s) and allows parallel processing. I've created a prototype app that also uses MVVM-Light for the RelayCommands. The example "aTplTest.7z" is located at https://skydrive.live.com/redir?resid=DA3E430C1A5F3B81!186&authkey=!AOOWYGbB_PToC5A

The prototype mostly works (just runs Fibonacci calcs for testing) except for the following.

1. How do you show the view as a dialog and have it start the long running process automatically? (At the moment the work-a-round is to make the user press a Start button.)
2. How do you allow the user to close the view and not have the task create an exception when cancelling the current job instance?

(For example, if the user presses the view close window button, the catch's Invoke method creates another exception.)

```
    private bool CreateVouchers(int[] workList)
    {
        var loopOptions = new ParallelOptions();
        loopOptions.CancellationToken = TokenSource.Token;
        var success = false;
        try
        {
            Parallel.ForEach(workList, loopOptions, t => BuildVoucher(t));
            success = true;
        }
        catch (OperationCanceledException)
        {
            var scm = new Action(ShowCancellationMessage);
            Application.Current.Dispatcher.Invoke(DispatcherPriority.Normal, scm);
        }
        return success;
    }
```

I'll update this post and the source example with any solutions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To automatically start your long running process just add the following Window_Loaded handler to the code-behind where you defined your Window_Closing handler:

```
private void Window_Closing(object sender, System.ComponentModel.CancelEventArgs e)
{
    var viewModel = (VoucherBuilderViewModel)this.DataContext;
    viewModel.CancelCommand.Execute(null);
}

private void Window_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    var viewModel = (VoucherBuilderViewModel)this.DataContext;
    viewModel.RunJob();
}
```

Of course, don't forget to register the event handler in your XAML:

```
<Window Closing="Window_Closing" Loaded="Window_Loaded">
```

And to get rid of the exception when closing the window just add the following null check:

```
catch (OperationCanceledException)
{
    if (Application.Current != null)
    {
        var scm = new Action(ShowCancellationMessage);
        Application.Current.Dispatcher.Invoke(DispatcherPriority.Normal, scm);
    }
}
```

Comment: Of course. Thanks. With the close issue, I ended up performing a check if the ViewModel was busy and then e.cancel = true in the closing telling the user to cancel the process first.

Answer (score 0):

Not totally sure of all the details you are asking, but I can try to address both questions.

1. **Showing the view as a dialog:     Do you mean this is a modal
   Dialog? If the view derives from Window (which I'm assuming it
   doesn't as that would be too easy) just call view.ShowDialog();

   As for starting the long running process, either attach to OnLoaded,
   or run it in the constructor.**
2. **Register a way to close the view that includes using your
   cancellation token on loop options.  In Build Voucher, simply check
   to see if the cancellation token has had a requested cancellation
   and gracefully stop producing messages and clean up.**

I hope this helps.  If you add comments I may be able to shed more light.

Comment: 1) yes, the OnLoaded with getting the ViewModel from the Context was the answer. 2) bugged87 helped with the solution. Thanks.